# How to get screenshot from clipboard?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I try to get a screenshot out of the clipboard. I have wrote the following code that is triggerd by the PRINT-Key:

```
IDataObject obj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
var formats = obj.GetFormats();
```

But the "formats" are empty. All tutorials in the www tell my to do it this way but I can´t explain the above behaviour.

(I use C# withe .NET 4.0 on a Windows 7 x64)

Comment: Sounds to me like you need another PRINT key.  You never said "but another program can see it".

Comment: well I thought about to explain in my post that the screenshot was taken because i can past it to paint but i hoped that it is obvious ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that my keylistener blocked the windows-keylistener. Which is why windows haven´t saved the screenshot in the clipboard :-(

workaround:

```
// get the bounding area of the screen containing (0,0)
// remember in a multidisplay environment you don't know which display holds this point
Drawing.Rectangle bounds = Forms.Screen.GetBounds(System.Drawing.Point.Empty);

// create the bitmap to copy the screen shot to
Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

// now copy the screen image to the graphics device from the bitmap
using (Drawing.Graphics gr = Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    gr.CopyFromScreen(Drawing.Point.Empty, Drawing.Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the `Clipboard.GetImage();` method?

[Here's the MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getimage.aspx)

```
Image GetClipboardImage()
{
    if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
    {
         return Clipboard.GetImage();
    }
    // add error handling
}
```

Comment: Are you using WinForms?  I tried the code in a project and it works fine.

Comment: using wpf, maybe thats it but still why?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the [`GetImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getimage.aspx) method?

```
image = Clipboard.GetImage();
```

There is more information at the link provided, which also shows how to check if an image exists on the clipboard (`ContainsImage`) - but you might need to take some other steps, depending on *when* the object was written to the clipboard.

I'm not even aware of a `GetFormats` method and can't find one exposed by the Windows Forms, or WPF Clipboard classes.

Comment: formats shows me which formats in the clipboard, for example: PlainText, RTF, TIFF, PNG, ..